# How do I insert a QuickParts BuildingBlock in an Outlook appointment using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I have a QuickParts Building Block in Microsoft Outlook 2016 called "Meeting purpose block." I can use it by navigating through the ribbon, but I cannot figure out how to write VBA, i.e., a macro, to do the same thing.

[image: screenshot from Outlook]

From what I can tell, the Building Block is part of a Microsoft Word template named "NormalEmail.dotm", so I assume that I will have to use the Word VBA library in my code.

Comment: So you need to 1) figure out how to obtain the Word.Document object from Outlook and 2) figure out how to insert a BuildingBlock in the Word object model. I'm pretty sure you can find some answers around here for both

Comment: @jbjstam: I looked, but could not find any answers.

Comment: Ok, posted a minimal example for you

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a reference to the Word tlb or change all the Word.* variables to Variant

```
Sub InsertBuildingBlock()
    Dim oInspector As Inspector
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim oTemplate As Word.Template
    Dim oBuildingBlock As Word.BuildingBlock

    ''Or get the inspector some other way
    Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector

    If oInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then

        ''The property WordEditor is a Word.Document
        Set oDoc = oInspector.WordEditor

        ''This inserts the firt building block in the first template
        ''This is based on a simple recording action in Word
        Set wordApp = oDoc.Application
        Set oTemplate = wordApp.templates(1)
        Set oBuildingBlock = oTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries(1)

        oBuildingBlock.Insert wordApp.Selection.Range, True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah geez. I forgot to test whether this answer was correct, and I don't have access to Outlook anymore. Can anyone else confirm that the code indeed works?